# Implicit function theorem and systems of equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I have some troubles with the next exercise. It's so hard. I have been trying and I can't found the solution.

> In the next system of equations, can we express in a
> neighborhood of the point $\overline{w_0}=(\overline{x_0},t_0)=\left(\pi,\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2},1\right)$ the variables $x$ and $y$?
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \cos(x)+t\sin(y) & = & 0\\
> \sin(x)-\cos(ty) & = & 0
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

Then, we consider the functions $f_1=\cos(x)+t\sin(y)=0$ and $f_2=\sin(x)-\cos(ty)=0$. We want to see that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $$f(\overline{x},t)=(f_1(\overline{x},t),f_2(\overline{x},t))$$ is Continuously Differentiable, but is clear, because the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous. Then, $f\in C^{1}$

In this way, the derivative matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin(x) & t\cos(y) & t\sin(y)\\
\cos(x) & t\sin(y) & y\sin(ty)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We should to see the sub-matrix

$$
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\sin(x) & t\cos(y)\\
\cos(x) & t\sin(y)
\end{array}
\right)_{\overline{w_0}}
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
-1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
$$

The determinant of this matrix, clearly, is zero and thus, the matrix is not invertible. Then, the hypothesis of the Implicit function theorem are not fulfilled. Then, what can I do?

We are looking for a function $g(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ such that $f(g(t),t)=0$ and moreover $\left( \pi,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=f(1)=(x(1),y(1))$. If the hypothesis of the theorem are not fulfilled, how can we conclude that we can't express the variables $x$ and $y$? Or, can we although the hypothesis are not fulfilled?
Really I need help with this.
I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: Check your derivative matrix! (Unfortunately the problem remains.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the change of variables
$$
x= \pi +u, \quad y= \pi/2 +v, \quad t =1+s,
$$
then your problem becomes
$$
\cos u -(1+s) \cos v =0, \quad
\sin u - \sin (v+ \pi s/2 +sv)=0,  
$$
and your problem is now around $(u,v,s)=(0,0,0)$. But if $s=0$, you have the problem
$$
\cos u - \cos v =0, \quad
\sin u - \sin v=0,  
$$
which has solutions $u=v$ for all $u$. So, near $s=u=v=0$ the Implicit function Theorem does not work because there is no map $s \mapsto (u(s),v(s))$ which defines a unique function (you have a line of solutions!)